# Error compiling CSS assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-3.2

When I load my web page, I am getting above error along with

```
Started GET "/assets/application.css" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-03-05 10:07:42 +0530
Error compiling asset application.css:
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
  (in /Users/ritvvijparrikh/Projects/tr/app/assets/stylesheets/tr/sprites.css.scss)
Served asset /application.css - 500 Internal Server Error
```

My file sprites.css.scss was not changed for long time. But then I recently upgraded to Rails 3.2.2

My sprites.css.scss file is

```
/* Public Area Sprites */
.public_sprites {
  background: asset-url('public_area.jpg', image) no-repeat top left;
}

.sprite-aws{ background-position: 0 0; width: 159px; height: 58px; display: inline-block }
.sprite-gr{ background-position: 0 -108px; width: 111px; height: 91px; display: inline-block }
.sprite-hn{ background-position: 0 -249px; width: 111px; height: 91px; display: inline-block }
.sprite-i1{ background-position: 0 -390px; width: 28px; height: 30px; display: inline-block }
.sprite-i2{ background-position: 0 -470px; width: 28px; height: 30px; display: inline-block }
.sprite-i3{ background-position: 0 -550px; width: 28px; height: 28px; display: inline-block }
.sprite-i4{ background-position: 0 -628px; width: 28px; height: 28px; display: inline-block }
.sprite-kb{ background-position: 0 -706px; width: 112px; height: 92px; display: inline-block }
.sprite-nb{ background-position: 0 -848px; width: 111px; height: 91px; display: inline-block }
.sprite-pk{ background-position: 0 -989px; width: 111px; height: 91px; display: inline-block }
.sprite-postmark{ background-position: 0 -1130px; width: 171px; height: 35px; display: inline-block }
.sprite-rd{ background-position: 0 -1215px; width: 111px; height: 91px; display: inline-block }
.sprite-rp{ background-position: 0 -1356px; width: 111px; height: 91px; display: inline-block }
.sprite-sb{ background-position: 0 -1497px; width: 111px; height: 91px; display: inline-block }
.sprite-seal{ background-position: 0 -1638px; width: 119px; height: 45px; display: inline-block }
.sprite-slider1{ background-position: 0 -1733px; width: 500px; height: 320px; display: inline-block }
.sprite-slider2{ background-position: -550px 0; width: 500px; height: 320px; display: inline-block }
.sprite-slider3{ background-position: -550px -370px; width: 500px; height: 320px; display: inline-block }
.sprite-sr{ background-position: -550px -740px; width: 112px; height: 92px; display: inline-block }
.sprite-track_big{ background-position: -550px -882px; width: 415px; height: 304px; display: inline-block }
.sprite-trustlaw{ background-position: -550px -1236px; width: 216px; height: 72px; display: inline-block }
.sprite-unknown{ background-position: -550px -1358px; width: 74px; height: 74px; display: inline-block }
.sprite-vm{ background-position: -550px -1482px; width: 111px; height: 91px; display: inline-block }



/* Contact Sprites */
.contact_sprites {
  background: asset-url('contact.png', image) no-repeat top left;
}
.sprite-email{ background-position: 0 0; width: 17px; height: 17px; display: inline-block }
.sprite-facebook{ background-position: 0 -67px; width: 17px; height: 17px; display: inline-block }
.sprite-linkedin{ background-position: 0 -134px; width: 17px; height: 17px; display: inline-block }
.sprite-mobile{ background-position: 0 -201px; width: 17px; height: 17px; display: inline-block }
.sprite-phone1{ background-position: 0 -268px; width: 17px; height: 17px; display: inline-block }
.sprite-phone2{ background-position: 0 -335px; width: 16px; height: 13px; display: inline-block }
.sprite-skype{ background-position: 0 -398px; width: 17px; height: 17px; display: inline-block }
.sprite-twitter{ background-position: 0 -465px; width: 17px; height: 17px; display: inline-block }
.sprite-website{ background-position: 0 -532px; width: 17px; height: 17px; display: inline-block }
.sprite-youtube{ background-position: 0 -599px; width: 17px; height: 17px; display: inline-block }

/* Login Area Sprites */
.login_sprites {
  background: asset-url('login_area.png', image) no-repeat top left;
}
.sprite-calendar_39x39{ background-position: 0 0; width: 39px; height: 39px; display: inline-block }
.sprite-deletex{ background-position: 0 -89px; width: 17px; height: 17px; display: inline-block }
.sprite-off{ background-position: 0 -156px; width: 95px; height: 27px; display: inline-block }
.sprite-on{ background-position: 0 -233px; width: 94px; height: 27px; display: inline-block }
.sprite-status_gray{ background-position: 0 -310px; width: 12px; height: 13px; display: inline-block }
.sprite-status_green{ background-position: 0 -373px; width: 12px; height: 13px; display: inline-block }
.sprite-status_red{ background-position: 0 -436px; width: 12px; height: 12px; display: inline-block }
.sprite-status_yellow{ background-position: 0 -498px; width: 12px; height: 13px; display: inline-block }
```

Comment: I'm having a similar issue after upgrading to Rails 3.2.2, but I wasn't sure it was because of that or something completely different. The strange thing is that `cap staging deploy` works but `cap production deploy` does not.

Comment: I'm having the same issue here as well. I've found that commenting out the lines that use the `asset-url` helper fixes the error (but obviously break your stylesheet), so I think it's related to how this helper looks up asset files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having the same problem. I solved the problem following the configurations described on this post:

http://blog.55minutes.com/2012/01/getting-compass-to-work-with-rails-31-and-32/

In my case, the problem was I didn't rename application.css to application.scss.